# Is it possible to change the sent file in discord python?

Tags: python, discord.py

I need to change embed with local file (photo) from my machine.
To send embed, you need to send the file along with it, but it cannot be changed.
When i try to do this:

**My Code:**

```
embed = discord.Embed(title = "Title here", description = "",
                              timestamp = datetime.utcnow(),
                              color = 0x26ad00)

file = discord.File(f"images/{msg.id}.png")
embed.set_image(url = f"attachment://{msg.id}.png")
await msg.edit(file = file, embed = embed)
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type File is not JSON serializable

There is no such error when using a link from the internet directly *(without file from link)*. I think I need to upload my photos to the internet with a photo API or something else but it is very slow, is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack. Just looking through, you forgot an await by your msg.edit. Maybe try that?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add this in the question, but in the code it is (it's not fixed problem)

Comment: Does it work if you try to send it without editing?

Comment: @EpicEfeathers Yes it works without editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *cannot* change the attachments to a message after it has been sent. Discord simply doesn't allow it. If you check the discord.py [documentation for `discord.Message.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.edit), you'll see that the `file` parameter is not accepted. Your error is caused by discord.py trying to convert the file to a JSON to be sent with the API request

---

That said, there is a workaround to change the image. As you noted, the URL you provide to `discord.Embed.set_image` does not have to point to an attachment - it can point to any image that can be accessed by Discord. If you were to send a message containing the new image somewhere (say in a secret channel only you and your bot have access to), you could then use the URL for that attachment in your edit somewhat like this:

```py
# you need to define secret_channel before this (example below)
secret_channel = bot.get_channel(12345)  # where 12345 would be your secret channel id
file = discord.File(f"images/{msg.id}.png")
temp_message = await secret_channel.send(file = file)
attachment = temp_message.attachments[0]

embed = discord.Embed(title = "Title here", description = "",
                      timestamp = datetime.utcnow(),
                      color = 0x26ad00)
embed.set_image(url = attachment.url)
await msg.edit(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async def edit_attachments(message: discord.Message, files: File):
    await message.remove_attachments(message.attachments)
    await message.add_files(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the solution!

```
message = await message.channel.send('Live') 
while True:
    mss().shot(output="foo.png") #mss is used to make a screenshot but the basic concept is you have to update the image file but keep the filename
    await message.add_files(discord.File(fp="foo.png"))
```

If this doesn't work make sure you have `intents.message_content` enabled

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation, you need to clear the existing attachments:

```py
await message.edit(
    files=[File('blah/blah/smurfs-having-a-party.jpg')],
    attachments=[],
)
```

*(The code is py-cord, I hope it's the same in discord.py)*

Docs:

- [Edit message](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#edit-message)
- [Uploading files](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files)

Answer (score 0):

[`discord.Message.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.edit) does not accept the `file` parameter, but you can use the `attachments` parameter. Parameter is set to a list of files/attachments, that the edited message will have:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Title here", description="",
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                              color=0x26ad00)

file = discord.File(f"images/{msg.id}.png")
embed.set_image(url=f"attachment://{msg.id}.png")
await msg.edit(embed=embed, attachments=[file])
```

If you use slash commands, you can do the same thing with [`discord.Interaction.edit_original_response`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.edit_original_response)
or
[`discord.InteractionResponse.edit_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.edit_message)